# Complement of two arrays in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Very simple problem, I am on the right track, I have to use predicates but couldn't find the solution.
I have two arrays:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [1, 2]
```

I want to have an aray C = A \ B that is

```
C = [3, 4]
```

Comment: Do you want all elements that are in A but not B, or all elements that are in either A or B but not both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the right tool for the task. What you're describing here is the **set** operation "difference".

```
NSMutableSet *first = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, @4, nil];
NSSet *second = [NSSet setWithObjects:@1, @2, nil];
[first minusSet:second];
```

If you **really really really** need to work with arrays, you can convert between arrays and sets too:

```
NSArray *array = [someSet allObjects];
```

or

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:someArray];
```

Comment: While I agree that `NSSet` looks like the right tool, the conversion to `NSSet` may be bothersome. Without knowing the context it's hard to tell.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with `removeObjectsFromArray:`

```
NSArray * arrayA = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];
NSArray * arrayB = @[ @1, @2 ];

NSMutableArray * arrayC = [arrayA mutableCopy];
[arrayC removeObjectsInArray:arrayB];
```

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments and also proposed by H2CO3, if you don't have a valid reason to use `NSArray`, the most convenient solution is to change data structure and switch to `NSSet`, which has the support for set difference, using the method `-minusSet:`.

**EDIT 2**
As Sven noted in the comments, your objects must respond properly to `hash` and `isEqual:` in order to use `removeObjectsInArray:`. In the above example everything will work just fined, since `NSNumber` has a default implementation for those methods, but in case you're using a custom class you need to explicitly override them.

Comment: This works correctly for the example as given; there's no reason to bother converting to a set.

Comment: The `mutableCopy` method returns an `NSMutableArray`, but you should really use sets for set operations, unless there is a really good reason not to.

Comment: The type of `arrayC` was indeed incorrect (fixed now). The OP asked a solution about arrays. While `NSSet` is the right tool for this kind of operations, it may be the wrong one given the OP's context. As far as we know he needs to work on `NSArray` and the above code will work just fine. That said, I don't understand the downvotes, but I'm open to discussions.

Comment: Don’t forget that `NSArray` keeps the order of objects and you can have the same object more than once. And `removeObjectsFromArray:` is probably using a `NSSet` internally since the documentation states that the objects in the array need to implement `hash` and `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
NSArray * arrayA = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];
NSArray * arrayB = @[ @1, @2 ];

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [arrayA indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if([arrayB containsObject:obj]){
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}];

NSArray *arrayC = [arrayA objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```